# What are the default ILM policies with Elasticsearch 7.8.1

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I recently upgraded from Elasticsearch version 5.6.3 to 7.8.1 using reindex API and could observe that following policies have got created:
ilm-history-ilm-policy
watch-history-ilm-policy
kibana-event-log-policy
ml-size-based-ilm-policy
slm-history-ilm-policy

We are using eck operator for installing ES v7.8.1 and am unable to find any custom policies created. Are these default policies? Can you help with any supporting documents for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are default ILM policies created when bootstrapping a new cluster.

- `ilm-history-ilm-policy`: whenever an ILM policy gets executed, [the result of each execution](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.8/ilm-settings.html) (`indices.lifecycle.history_index_enabled`, default: true) gets logged into indexes called `ilm-history-*` and there's an ILM policy called `ilm-history-ilm-policy` governing the lifecycle of those historical indexes.
- `slm-history-ilm-policy`: Same thing whenever a snapshot policy runs, the actions are stored in an index called `slm-history-*` and the ILM policy called `slm-history-ilm-policy` governs the lifecycle of those indexes
- kibana-event-log-policy: Same for all Kibana events stored in the `kibana-event-log-*` indexes
- watch-history-ilm-policy: Same for all watcher executions

Comment: I tried this command: curl -k https://username:password@localhost:9200/_ilm/policy and received the response with the highlighted policies. so are these indices or policies?

Comment: How are these getting created? I can see in the logs there is the following xpack -> "message": "loaded module [x-pack-ilm]. Is this xpack leading to these?

Comment: I've rephrased my answer